# Python: How to create attributes that depend on other attributes within an instance

Tags: python, class, attr

I am extremely new to Python have just started using classes and dictionaries for the first time (also first StackOverflow post) but have never used an instance. I successfully created a Player class but since I wanted different enemies, I created an Enemy class. I separated the attributes on new lines for personal preference.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health, maxhealth, head, torso, legs, feet, armor, weapon, damage, gold):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.head = head
        self.torso = torso
        self.legs = legs
        self.feet = feet
        self.armor = armor
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.damage = damage
        self.gold = gold

skeleton = Enemy("Skeleton",
                  60,
                  60,
                  armors['leatherhelm'],
                  armors['leathertorso'],
                  armors['leatherleggings'],
                  armors['leatherboots'],
                  Enemy.head['defense']+Enemy.torso['defense']+Enemy.legs['defense']+Enemy.feet['defense'],
                  weapons['rustycutlass'],
                  1+Enemy.weapon['damage'], 
                  33)
```

An error occurs, `type object 'Enemy' has no attribute 'head'` (assuming that Enemy does not have `torso`, `legs`, `feet`, and `weapon` either). I originally tried `self.head` before realizing why it does not work, and also tried `skeleton.head`. Is there a way for me to use these attributes that depend on each other? Also, do I need any of the parentheses? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In response to OP's comment, how about moving calculated attributes (`damage` and `armor`) into the `Enemy` class to avoid forcing them into the `__init__` call?  That way, when armor is updated and/or the weapon is changed, those properties will still be correct.

Example:

```
armors = {
    "leatherhelm": {"defense": 10},
    "leathertorso": {"defense": 5},
    "leatherleggings": {"defense": 3},
    "leatherboots": {"defense": 1},
}
weapons = {
    "rustycutlass": {"damage": 6}
}

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health, maxhealth, head, torso, legs, feet, weapon, gold):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.maxhealth = maxhealth
        self.head = head
        self.torso = torso
        self.legs = legs
        self.feet = feet
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.gold = gold
    
    @property
    def armor(self):
        return self.head["defense"] + self.torso['defense'] + self.legs['defense'] + self.feet['defense']
    
    @property
    def damage(self):
        return self.weapon["damage"] + 1

skeleton = Enemy("Skeleton",
                  60,
                  60,
                  armors['leatherhelm'],
                  armors['leathertorso'],
                  armors['leatherleggings'],
                  armors['leatherboots'],
                  weapons['rustycutlass'],
                  33)

print(skeleton.damage)
print(skeleton.armor)
```

Output:

```
print(skeleton.damage)
print(skeleton.armor)
```

Comment: This does work but I was fearing if the enemy changes their weapon or armor, it would still have defense and attack of their old equipment. It is more of a problem for the Player then Enemy but still would like that to work. For example:

```
if skeleton.hp >30:
   skeleton.weapon = weapons['secretattack']
```